# Is there a way i could wrap some get methods for an angular reactive form control into one function

Tags: javascript, angular, function, angular-reactive-forms

Good day, this is my first time asking a question here and am pretty positive of a solution, In my component, I have an angular reactive form setup below and some getters(what i call lols) but it's a bit messy, i mean this form controls are actually much, please is there a way i could wrap this getters into a function so i wouldn't be having several lines of codes. Am a javascript newbie.

```
formName = new FormGroup({
    accNum: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    appName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    ...
    Addr: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

//form getters
  get accNum(){
    return this.formName.get('accNum')
  }

  get appName(){
    return this.formName.get('appName');
  }
   ...

 get Addr(){
    return this.formName.get('Addr');
  }
```

I am doing this so i would be able to set form control in my html template like this.

```
<input formControlName="accNum" type="text" class="form-control">
<input formControlName="appName" type="text" class="form-control">
<input formControlName="Addr" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: it's NOT necesary create getter for the controls. `formControlName` need a "string" that it's the name of the formControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.formName.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      Object.keys(this.formName.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
        console.log(this.formName.get(key).value);
      });
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-pz1gmr?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a generic method which returns a formControl object.

In your **.ts** file, write a function like this.

```
getFormControl(controlName: string) {
    //return the formControl object of the respective 'controlName'
    return this.formName.get(controlName);
}
```

Then, In your template

```
<input formControlName="accNum" type="text">
<span *ngIf="getFormControl('accNum').errors?.required">
    accNum can't be empty
</span>

<input formControlName="accName" type="text">
<span *ngIf="getFormControl('accName').errors?.required">
    accName can't be empty
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this works for me and it's actually very comprehensible to me, once again thanks alot

Comment: @darkel, Glad it helped you. If you don't mind, could you please accept and upvote the answer.